# How to know DB Size when FILEGROWTH applied?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

MS SQL 2008.

I have a DataBase which use FILEGROWTH (this property specifies the growth increment of the DB.).

As soon as my DataBase reach the size of 40MB DB it will be expanded +20 MB (FILEGROWTH) till reach the MAXSIZE... Correct?

If it is Correct, how can I get the `Current Size` for all the Rows in any Tables in my DB... I would like to know if is possible have the Size for the Actual Content an not Db SIZE+FILEGROWTH.

Hope guys I can have a clear explanation, I'm pretty new with DB. Thanks for your help!

Here the code I use.

```
CREATE DataBase MyDB
ON PRIMARY
(
    NAME = 'MyDB',
    FILENAME = 'C:\Server\Data\DataBase\MyDB.mdf',  -- Location DataBase
    SIZE = 40 MB,
    MAXSIZE = 960 MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 20 MB
)
LOG ON
(
    NAME = 'MyDB',
    FILENAME = 'C:\Server\Data\DataBase\MyDB.ldf',  -- Location Log files
    SIZE = 20 MB,
    MAXSIZE = 960 MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 20 MB
)
WITH DB_CHAINING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way is to run [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) with no parameters

If you look at the code of this proc, you should see queries based on sys views etc of you want something slightly cleverer

Edit: I did this before: [How do I find out what tables have data in a file in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109248/how-do-i-find-out-what-tables-have-data-in-a-file-in-sql-server/1109289#1109289)

Comment: cool it is working, just for curiosity... do you know other way to do it?

Comment: @GibboK: just updated. yes, you can use queries based on sys.allocation_units etc. Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109248/how-do-i-find-out-what-tables-have-data-in-a-file-in-sql-server/1109289#1109289

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this. I will accept your answer thanks!